# Grep and extract specific data in multiple log files

Tags: sed, grep

I've got multiple log files in a directory and trying to extract just the timestamp and a section of the log line i.e. the value of the fulltext query param. Each query param in a request is separated by an ampersand(&) as shown below.

**Input**

> **30/Mar/2022:00:27:36** +0000 [59823] -> GET
> /libs/granite/omnisearch?p.guessTotal=1000&**fulltext=798**&savedSearches%40Delete=&
>
> **31/Mar/2022:00:27:36** +0000 [59823] -> GET
> /libs/granite/omnisearch?p.guessTotal=1000&**fulltext=Dyson+V7**&savedSearches%40Delete=&

**Intended Output**

> 30/Mar/2022:00:27:36  ->  798
>
> 31/Mar/2022:00:27:36  ->  Dyson+V7

I've got this command to recursively search over all the files in the directory.

`grep -rn "/libs/granite/omnisearch" ~/Downloads/ReqLogs/ > output.txt`

This prints the entire log line starting with the directory name, like so

`/Users/****/Downloads/ReqLogs/logfile1_2022-03-31.log:6020:31/Mar/2022:00:27:36 +0000 [59823] -> GET /libs/granite/omnisearch?p.guessTotal=1000&fulltext=798&savedSearches%4`

Please enlighten, How do i manipulate this to achieve the intended output.

Comment: The general features of my answer are all very common FAQs; please search before asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` can return the whole line or the string which matched. For extracting a different piece of data from the matching lines, turn to `sed` or Awk.

```
awk -v search="/libs/granite/omnisearch" '$0 ~ search { s = $0; sub(/.*fulltext=/, "", s); sub(/&.*/, "", s); print $1, s }' ~/Downloads/ReqLogs/*
```

or

```
sed -n '\%/libs/granite/omnisearch%s/ .*fulltext=\([^&]*\)&.*/\1/p' ~/Downloads/ReqLogs/*
```

The `sed` version is more succinct, but also somewhat more oblique.

`\%...%` uses the alternate delimiter `%` so that we can use literal slashes in our search expression.

The `s/ .../\1/p` then says to replace everything on the matching lines after the first space, capturing anything between `fulltext=` and `&`, and replace with the captured substring, then print the resulting line.

The `-n` flag turns off the default printing action, so that we only print the lines where the search expression matched.

The wildcard `~/Downloads/ReqLogs/*` matches all files in that directory; if you really need to traverse subdirectories, too, perhaps add `find` to the mix.

```
find ~/Downloads/ReqLogs -type f -exec sed -n '\%/libs/granite/omnisearch%s/ .*fulltext=\([^&]*\)&.*/\1/p' {} +
```

or similarly with the Awk command after `-exec`. The placeholder `{}` tells `find` where to add the name of the found file(s) and `+` says to put as many as possible in one go, rather than running a separate `-exec` for each found file. (If you want that, use `\;` instead of `+`.)

Comment: thank you for the detailed info, took me some time to digest all the info in your answer, well worth it.